# How can I make a unicode character logo nested within an <ul> into a web link?

Tags: unicode, hyperlink, html-lists

I'm new to this and have been racking my brain to figure something out:

```
<header>

<div>
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="logo">&#9775;</li>
    <li> <a href="url address"> Title</a></li>
    <li> <a href="url address"> Title</a></li>
    <li> <a href="url address"> Title</a></li>
    <li> <a href="url address"> Title</a></li>
    <li> <a href="url address"> Title</a></li>
</ul>

</header>
```

I would like to make the first list item (it is a unicode character taken from here: https://unicode-table.com/en/) into a clickable link going to a webpage.

Is there a way to do this using just HTMl and CSS?

I've tried different combinations of markup, and found something that worked...but it didn't pass verification.
This is what I had:

```
<li class="logo"><a href="url address">&#9775;</a></li>
```

It worked, but I found out you can't nest links within list items like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by “you can't nest links within list items like that”?

Comment: I mean when I ran the code through a verification service: https://validator.w3.org/    it told me that it wasn't proper HTML to have <a> elements nested within <li> elements

Answer (score 0):

Ah duh.

```
<ul>
<li class="logo"> <a href="https://url">&#9775;</a> </li>
</ul>
```

That worked, and passed the verification.